# Comparing strings with hour

Tags: javascript

Hy guys.

How can I compare this data...

```
var str = '09:29';
var parts = str.split(':');
minutes = parts[1]; 
hour = parts[2];
```

with actual hour?

I have a table with that value and want to compare if it is 5 minutes older than the actual time.

Thks folks.

Comment: Are you assuming that the time in `str` represents a time today? What about the time zone? Is it in 24 hour format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will be useful to get the actual time:

```
var d = new Date();
var curr_hour = d.getHours();
var curr_min = d.getMinutes();
```

Now you can either compare the hours and see if they are the same (or within 1 of each other to account for a difference in minutes), or you can do it mathematically, which is how I would do it.

```
if((((curr_hour * 60) + curr_min) == ((hour * 60) + minutes) + 5)){
    //Do something
}
```

This is how I would go about doing that.  I'd seperate the arithmetic logic out of the if statement though.

Edit:  Here is the code I would probably use.

```
var givenTime = (hour * 60) + minutes;
var systemTime = (curr_hour * 60) + curr_min;
var difference = Math.abs((givenTime + 5) - systemTime);

if(difference == 0){
   //do something
}
```